# How to define properties like Type<Protocol> in Swift?

Tags: swift

In ObjC it was possible to define properties like NSObject. How can I do something similar in Swift? I know that there is a way to combine protocols through protocol<A,B,C> but it does not work for types.

Comment: Do you think something like `Any`? It basically means any type that can conform to protocol (that is - not a function). It typealias of `protocol<>`.

Comment: What I am actually trying to define is a let of AnyObject type that conforms to UITextViewDelegate. Any is too generic, I am trying to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for protocol composition, here is an example:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

}

var viewController = MyViewController()
var someDelegate: protocol<UITextViewDelegate> = viewController
var backToViewController = someDelegate as MyViewController
```